# Is there an equivalent tool in python to mimic the behaviour of the pre-processor in C?

Tags: python, dry, function-declaration

It is not uncommon to want to define many different functions which shall have the same prototype in C.

```
int f(int x, int y, char z, char *w);
int g(int x, int y, char z, char *w);
int h(int x, int y, char z, char *w);
int i(int x, int y, char z, char *w);
int j(int x, int y, char z, char *w);
```

To leave open the possibility of adding an additional parameter to every single one of these functions without having to change many lines of code, I can use the preprocessor to stay flexible:

```
#define FUNCTION(func) int (func)(int x, int y, char z, char *w)
```

and then replace my prototypes with

```
FUNCTION(f);
FUNCTION(g);
FUNCTION(h);
FUNCTION(i);
FUNCTION(j);
```

And then when I go to define the functions I would use lines like:

```
FUNCTION(f)
{
    //do something with x,y,z,w
}

FUNCTION(g)
{
    //do something else with x,y,z,w
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in python?  i.e. is it possible define many functions in Python, all of which take exactly the same parameters, then modify their parameters (say adding or removing one) by changing a single line?

Comment: How does this add a parameter to anything?

Comment: Nothing.  But if I wanted to add a parameter to every single function, I'd only have to change the line that begins with '#define'.

Comment: Why would you want to add a parameter to every function without also changing the function body to do something with that parameter?

Comment: You could create a decorator whose behavior is controlled by a parameter which is defined towards the top of the file  and decorate the functions with this common decorator.

Comment: @Samwise At run time I will be calling one of these functions without knowing which one it is.  Some parameters are only used for some of the functions.  It's conceivable that as I add new functions to the list, one of them may need more information.  In this case I might add a new parameter.  While the old functions won't need it, I need them to be expecting it.  The MWE in my question hides the motivation for this.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this in Python than what you did in C...

Comment: @Samwise I am starting to think this also.  Upon further reflection, this seems like a situation where defining each function to accept **kwargs is much more natural and pythonic.  Once I flesh this out further I will append an appropriate edit to my question.

Comment: Yes, I’m not personally a fan of **kwargs because they’re antithetical to well-defined function contracts, but your use case sounds more wild-west so they’re probably the right thing.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't forward-declare functions in Python the way you might in C, so the premise of this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  The closest analogy would be in type declarations, which you can indeed alias:

```
from typing import Callable

FUNCTION = Callable[[int, int, str, str], int]
```

You can also have functions that themselves return functions, and potentially eliminate a lot of repetition that way, but your example doesn't include the body of the functions so  that doesn't really map.

For the case you describe in your edit, you could just not declare the argument types and use *args instead:

```
def f(*args):
    x, y, z, w = args
```

Or for a typesafe solution (since it's hard to type *args and **kwargs), you could have these functions take a single (typed) tuple argument:

```
FUNCTION_ARGS = Tuple[int, int, str, str]

def f(args: FUNCTION_ARGS):
    # next line will throw a mypy error if it doesn't match FUNCTION_ARGS
    x, y, z, w = args
```

Comment: Perhaps I focused on the wrong thing in my examples.  The macro could just as well be used when defining the body of the functions.  I've edited my question to reflect this.

In any event, I'll take a look at the Callable module.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Standard Python has no built-in macro facilities and no support for static generative meta-programming except for `eval`/`exec`.

With the exclusion of `eval/exec` Python only provides dynamic (run-time) metaprogramming and apparently this is a design choice; for example it does provide decorators, that can cover some use cases. Also the reading (parsing) of Python source code is cast in stone and there's no way to extend the syntax.

The easy way to create functions and classes at runtime is by building the source code for them as a text string and invoking `eval` or `exec` on it. This is what the standard library does for example for `namedtuple`.

In addition almost all of the low-level parts of the Python VM are exposed; you have access to Python bytecode and you can for example generate functions that way, but that's a quite challenging operation because you need to take care about a lot of details (e.g. stack effect) and moreover some of those internals are not guaranteed stable between Python versions. It's in theory possible to reimplement `exec` in Python itself using only Python, but that would be quite difficult because you've to rewrite a sizeable part of Python compiler (that is written in C) yourself.

There is also someone that [tried to add macro power to Python](https://pypi.org/project/MacroPy/) just using what Python provides (or forgot to forbid)... I've no experience with it however.

Comment: I'm not quite convinced by it, but the book "Serious Python" by Julien Danjou has a chapter on using the `ast` module for metaprogramming in Python, so perhaps saying that Python has "no support" is too strong. Other than that quibble, good answer.

Comment: It's a bit odd to say python has no support for meta-programming, when it is listed in the wikipedia page on metaprogramming as language that supports metaclasses. I would say python has very strong support for meta-programming, it just doesn't directly support macros.

Comment: @Dunes: it all boils down to what you mean with metaprogramming. It has some form of it (decorators) and the low-level stuff is there (you can create classes or function objects) but there's no support in the language for passing, manipulating or returning code; you can only pass classes or functions, not code. It has support for runtime introspection, and that also could be considered some partial form of metaprogramming. If you want to call metaprogramming what python provides then you need to invent a wider more powerful term for what for example Lisp provides.

Comment: You can definitely manipulate and return code. It's just generally discouraged. Using the `ast` module, things like macropy (using only stdlib features) can take `f[_ * _]`and transform it into `def f(_0): return _0 * _0`. You can even get python to interpret `range(5) | pow(_, 2) | sum` as `sum(pow(n, 2) for n in range(5)`. Python gives full access to functions and classes, the ability to use reflections on those objects, decompile code objects, transform them and recompile them. It's just the general mantra is: keep it simple and stick to decorators.

Comment: @Dunes: "You can even get python to interpret range(5) | pow(_, 2) | sum as sum(pow(n, 2) for n in range(5)". No you cannot, or to say it better it's a quite difficult operation because you need to write a compiler and do that by replacing code objects. What is somewhat easy to do is having it **behaving** more or less the same, but doing the re-interpretation of "metaprogram" at runtime for each execution. Saying that it's the same is like saying that a macro and a function are the same.